# $f(n+1)=f(n)/2+1$; $f(1)=4$; general formula for $f(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

As the question says, but note, as this is a sequence question (I am trying to find general formula for the sequence $4,3,2.25,...$) we assume that $n$ is greater than or equal to $1$. At first, I thought I could solve this as a geometric series but then saw the 'plus $1$' which sort of turned things on their head for me. Do you know of any ways to find the general formula? Thank you for any comments or answers.

Comment: Hint: $f(n+1) - 2 = ?$

Comment: I suppose I'll expand on @achillehui 's hint.  $$\overbrace{f(n+1)-2}^{u_{n+1}}=\frac{\overbrace{f(n)-2}^{u_n}}2\implies u_n=\frac{u_1}{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\begin{align}f(n)&=1+\frac12f(n-1)\\&=1+\frac12+\frac14f(n-2)\\&=1+\frac12+\frac14+\frac18f(n-3)\\\text{(induction)}&=\frac1{2^t}f(n-t)+\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}\frac1{2^k}\\&=\frac1{2^{n-1}}f(1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac1{2^k}\\&=2^{3-n}+2-2^{2-n}\\&=2+2^{2-n}\end{align}$$

Comment: @Ovi Thanks... was honestly aiming for a hint, but it just happened.

Comment: Is this a common way of solving recursive sequences? Sorry I don't really know anything about them.

Comment: @Ovi It's a good way to tackle simple ones.  Work out first few steps, spot pattern, prove by induction, and viola.  (rather than start with $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots$ and trying to guess the pattern)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: look for a solution of the form $f(n) = a + b r^n$ where $a$, $b$ and $r$ are constants.

Comment: Hmm I would've thought the +1 would show up as a $kn$ term in the expression for $f(n)$.

Comment: @Ovi Robert's ansatz is a linear combination of two exponentials, one with base $1$. What you're proposing is the limit when bases match, which is why it would apply if we deleted the halving but won't if we don't.

Comment: @J.G. Ah okay got it

Answer (score 4):

Put $u_n=f (n)-b$, with $b $ such that

$u_{n+1}=ku_n $.

thus

$$\frac {f (n)}{2}+1-b=k (f (n)-b) $$

from this

$$k=\frac 12 , b=2. $$

$$u_n=u_1 k^{n-1}=2(\frac {1}{2})^{n-1} $$
and

> $$f (n)=2+u_n=2+2^{2-n}$$